# Azure durable/entity functions startup delay

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a scenario where an azure function(http trigger) calls an orchestrator function, which calls multiple entities/activies.
The azure function then waits for the orchestrator to finish all its subtasks.
The following image shows a simplified sequence diagram.

[image: Sequence diagram]

**The problem:**

Calls to the orchestrator or entity function often(>20% of the time) take 15-20s to start executing(marked red in the diagram).

**What I tried so far:**

- Switched the service plan from consumption(serverless) to premium with a minimum of 5 instances(=more than the number of activities/entities being called).

  => No cold start of new instances should occur
- Called the http trigger many times in succession (but one after the other)

  => Some calls work, some don't, seems random
- Gave it a few minutes between calls to the http trigger

**When I run it locally with azurite, it works flawless every time**

Why do the orchestator or entity functions often take so much time to start executing when hosted in Azure?

**Update:**

- Changed maxQueuePollingInterval down to 3 seconds. No change in behavior.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting "maxQueuePollingInterval"? [Link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=csharp%2C2x-durable-functions#host-json) It is polling the storage queues and if there are no messages, it'll set a larger wait time for next polling. Default is 30 seconds at max. Note that lowering this can increase Storage costs as you are making more requests there.

Comment: @juunas I tried lowering maxQueuePollingInterval down to 3 seconds. I still have delays of 20 seconds+ from scheduled to starting in entity/orchestration functions.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Our delay seems to be almost 2 minutes in some cases